# Unity not supported on an HP Pavillion g6

Tags: unity, 11.04, hp-pavilion

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my new HP Pavillion g6 laptop. Unity was running from the liveCD. However, when I installed it, it wouldn't work. I logged in using Ubuntu Classic, and installed the proprietary graphics driver, hoping this would make it work, but it didn't.

Choosing "ubuntu" or "ubuntu classic" from the login screen yields to the same thing: gnome2 without unity.

How do I enable Unity?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes with an integrated video driver. When you use another driver for your computer it is recommended to remove the native drivers.

Make sure you have installed the driver of your video card. (If it is an NVidia card, you must have the Xserver installed too).

Then, you can remove the native driver of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

This worked for me. Tell me if you have any problems.

Comment: No it didn't work :(
It logs into classic gnome without even notifying me (it only did the first time). I'm thinking there might be something that should be edited with the conf files...

p.s. I'm using ATI Radeon